# How can I restore a git clone to what it was the second to the last time it pushed to OM?

Tags: git

I have a git clone which I want to restore to what it was 7 days ago regardless of the fact that I made several commits and even a push from there to the origin master since then.  What I'm looking for is like a point-in-time-recovery, something based on a date/time and specific to the clone dir.  I don't want to change the content of the origin master (or any other clone) in the process.

Can something like this be done ?

Answer (score 2):

Assume you didn't "try to change" commit time via methods like `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` environment variable, you can see your local changes of the tracked `origin/master` using `git reflog`:

```
git reflog --date=iso origin/master
```

You can then identify which commit is at your desired date, and use `git update-ref` to change the `origin/master` pointer:

```
git update-ref refs/remote/origin/master 0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef
```

Comment: perfect.  Thanks

Comment: @daveg Do you know you can mark an answer as "accepted" by clicking the grey tick beside it?